# Calling getActualDefaultRingtoneUri requires WRITE_SETTINGS permission?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an app with VoIP capabilities, ringing using default ringtone.

To get ringtone I use:

`var defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.GetActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneType.Ringtone);`

context is my CallService

Now I have several reports (from Samsung A51) on AppCenter (without exception message):

```
    android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    android.provider.Settings.isCallingPackageAllowedToPerformAppOpsProtectedOperation Settings.java:22933
    android.provider.Settings.checkAndNoteWriteSettingsOperation Settings.java:22821
    com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateSystemSetting SettingsProvider.java:2504
    com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.insertSystemSetting SettingsProvider.java:2470
    com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call SettingsProvider.java:678

    JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
    JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
    RingtoneManager.GetActualDefaultRingtoneUri (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Media.RingtoneType type)
    CallService.CreateRingingNotification...
```

When I looked into Settings.java - it seems that I need WRITE_SETTINGS permission to get default ring tone? It's like it doesn't have one, creating it on request and can't create?

My app is in xamarin.android (not forms/maui), targeting sdk 31.

Should I add WRITE_SETTINGS permission just to get default ringing notification on some phones? Is there any other way to get default ringing notification?

Comment: I have tested this line code, it can work without the permission on the emulator. Did this just happened on the Samsung A51?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - yes, I have many users and it seems that this problem occurs only on this phone

Comment: Did you have a such phone to test it?

Comment: No, only crashes from App center

Comment: If so, you can try to add this permission for those users.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I was having the same issue as you.
On some Samsung devices, the app I work on was crashing when trying to obtain the default ringtone URI in order to set it as selected in the `RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER`.
The `SecurityException` is not coming from `RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(...)` itself but from a hidden call in Samsung's implementation that tries to set ringtone which requires permission. It happened only to some Samsung phones specifically after OTA update. Unfortunately I do not have a stack trace to show the complete calls.
For some reason some Samsung devices had `null` for `Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI`. Users were reporting "My Phone app rings and all notifications work" but our app could not get a Uri for ringtone(`Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI`).

At the end the faulty code portion was try/catch with a Toast and carry with the app a default sound for ringing where a ringtone Uri could not be obtained. Requesting the permission made no sense as the app does not manage(set/change) any System settings.

What solves the issue from the device itself is to go to Android Settings and set the device Ringtone to one that is coming from the OS itself. If you have established communication with users with this issue try this suggestion to them to confirm.